# Rav Saadia Gaon Siddur in English

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, prayer-book, english, saadya-gaon

Is there a English translation of Rav Saadia Gaon's siddur?

I've only been able to find PDF and print versions in Hebrew.

Comment: Most Jewish texts, particularly non "essential" ones, are not available in English translation. Is there some reason you'd think this would be?

Comment: No reason.  Hoping someone has made one available.

Comment: The basic tefillos would be the same, so why would you need a new translation of the siddur? Do you mean his commentary that went along with his siddur?

Comment: The commentary and the siddur in Hebrew/English would be useful for me.

Answer (score 4):

There is no English translation of R. Saadia's *siddur* commentary (cf. OP's comment), at present. There is only the original Arabic and Hebrew which was published by Profs. [Davidson](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Israel_Davidson), [Joel](https://he.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%A9%D7%9B%D7%A8_%D7%99%D7%95%D7%90%D7%9C), [Assaf](https://www.jta.org/1953/10/20/archive/prof-simcha-assaf-member-of-israels-supreme-court-dies/amp) -accessible [here](http://hebrewbooks.org/20685). However, of the most notable reviews of the siddur an extensive study of it was printed in English by Prof. [Louis Ginzberg](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Louis_Ginzberg) and appeared as a series of articles in the Jewish Quarterly Review ([here](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1451987?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents)) . The review was subsequently translated into Hebrew and printed in 'על הלכה ואגדה'.